# Adding text into textarea from google console automatically using Js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, console, userscripts

We have a form that contains one Text-area and one submit button. The main purpose of this form is to convert the English language(words) into the Thai language(words) or Vice versa. This form needs to be filled out many times a day and adding manually is so tiresome.

**The form looks like this:**

[image: here]

Is there any way to add (sentence/word) into this text-area and hit submit button automatically from the broswer console? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: nops i am looking for js that would automate entering text in the textarea and hit submit button automatically

Comment: Then you need to write a userscript, or write that logic into your actual application.  This process wouldn't involve the console at all

Comment: is that possible the load logic inside the script and load that script from console?